# To cut capers in the street

Tags: etymology, idioms

I understand that the phrase in the title means  "to behave frivolously".

E.g.:  *A bereaved person does not cut capers in the street, and neither does a failed pupil.*

Google gives around 3 links for the phrase, including [Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna (English edition)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.messagefrommasters.com%2FEbooks%2FSpiritual-Books%2FGospel_of_Sri_Ramakrishna.pdf&ei=anTFT_fwH8igsQLqqbS1Bg&usg=AFQjCNEQHrpd7VGjK0HlTmRo10CJoxXkBw&sig2=lrp9-OvJnRDYIKyiHN5i3w)  and  [Frederique ,](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38332/38332-8.txt)  a novel by Paul de  Kock .  [Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut+capers+in+the+street&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)  shows no hits between 1700-2000.

**Question**  Can you give me some idea of the origin of this phrase? And why it has hardly ever been used?

Comment: I highly recommend searching for obscure English phrases in the following online dictionary: [etymonline entry for caper](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=caper&allowed_in_frame=0) They do a pretty good job there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re probably looking for sense **b** below.  Another nuance of **caper** would be as  some sort of crime exploit / adventure / escapade.

> ## [caper, *n.²*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27402)
>
> **Pronunciation**:  `/ˈkeɪpə(r)/` 
>   **Etymology**:  apparently abbreviated < *capriole* n.: Florio has Italian ‘*capriola*   a capriole or caper in dancing’. Compare **caper** *v.¹*; also *cab < cabriolet.*
>
> - **a.** A frolicsome leap, like that of a playful kid; a frisky movement, *esp*. in dancing; said also of horses; *fig*. a fantastic proceeding or freak.
>
>   - 1592   R. Greene *Quip for Vpstart Courtier* sig. H2ᵛ,   You maister vsher of the dauncing schoole‥stand vpon your tricks and capers.
>   - a1616   Shakespeare *As you like It* (1623) ɪɪ. iv. 51   We that are true Louers, runne into strange capers.
>   - 1712   Pope *Spectator* 18 June,   An Hour in Secret, wherein he had his Frisks and Capers.
>   - 1856   F. L. Olmsted *Journey Slave States* 68   Jane [a horse] gave a little sympathizing caper.
> - **b.** ***to cut a caper*** or ***capers*** : to dance in a frolicsome way, to act fantastically. ***†to cut a caper on nothing***: to be hanged.
>
>   - *a*1616   Shakespeare Twelfth Night (1623) ɪ. iii. 116   *And*. Faith, I can cut a caper. *To*. And I can cut the mutton too't.
>   - 1691   A. Wood *Athenæ Oxon.* II. 262   By his high dancing and cutting of Capers‥he did‥sprain a vein.
>   - 1708   P. A. Motteux *Wks. F. Rabelais* ɪᴠ. xvi,   Two of the honestest Gentlemen in Catchpole-land had been made to cut a Caper on nothing.
>   - 1711   R. Steele *Spectator* No. 4. ⁋8   He can Dance, though he does not cut Capers.
>   - 1827   B. Disraeli *Vivian Grey* III. v. xv. 320   Executing the most splendid somersets, and cutting all species of capers.
> - **c.** *transf*. Any activity or pursuit, spec. a fashionable occupation. Also, a ‘game’, dodge, racket. (There are many shades of meaning in U.S., N.Z., and elsewhere.)
>
>   - 1839   *Spirit of Times* 9 Nov. 423/2   When they are short on't for cradles, a feedin trof is jest the caper.
>   - 1840   C. F. Hoffman *Greyslaer* I. 84   The bizness is a bad one, any how you can fix it, capting; but I think I understand the caper on't.
>   - 1851   H. Mayhew *London Labour* I. 416/1,   I used to dress tidy and very clean for the ‘respectable broken-down tradesman or reduced gentleman’ caper.
>   - 1867   *London Herald* 23 Mar. 221   ‘He'll get five years penal for this little caper,’ said the policeman.
>   - *a*1889   *Boston Herald* (D.A.E.),   Mind-reading is now the proper caper.
>   - 1897   J. Conrad *Nigger of ‘Narcissus’* iv. 81   ‘I know his caper,’ he said, in a low voice.
>   - 1926   J. Black *You can't Win* x. 131   If anything had gone wrong with this caper and we had to take a pinch.
>   - 1944   J. A. Lee *Shining with Shiner* 75   It's getting worse for this caper every year.
>   - 1959   *N.Z. Listener* 12 June 5/2   Marxism was the caper.
>   - 1959   Times 26 May 12/7   Now let's see if the car stops at all after that little caper.
>   - 1964   J. Burke *Hard Day's Night* v. 104,   I know your caper. The kidney punch and the rabbit clout.
>
> ### Compounds
>
> *Comb*.  **caper-cut** *n*. the cutting of a caper.  **caper-cutting** *adj*. that cuts capers:  **caper-witted** *adj*. of frivolous or unsteady mind.
>
> - a1640   J. Fletcher & P. Massinger *Loves Pilgrimage* ɪɪ. i, in F. Beaumont & J. Fletcher *Comedies & Trag.* (1647) sig. Aaaaaaaa4/2,   My poor child‥Your caper-cutting son has run away with.
> - *a*1670   J. Hacket *Scrinia Reserata* (1693) i. 227   Whatsoever any Caperwitted Man may observe.
> - 1875   R. Browning *Aristophanes' Apol.* 361   Those flute-girls—trash who‥fed eye with caper-cuts.

---

### Citation

> caper, n.2
>   Second edition, 1989; online version March 2012. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27402; accessed 29 May 2012. Earlier version first published in *New English Dictionary*, 1888.