# Difference between "to flounce", "to caper", and "to gambol"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In a sentence describing some children having some fun in a playroom:

> They would flounce, caper, and gambol all the time.

What are the differences between those three actions?

Comment: What confused you about what the dictionary said?

Comment: @tchrist - My dictionary gives me bunch of translations for each one of those words and many of them overlap, so I still don't know the essential difference between those words. Plus, my dictionary gives me ALL possible meanings of those words, while in the context of the sentence that I brought up in my question only some of those meanings, I guess, should be considered, however, my dictionary doesn't tell me which meanings in my case I should consider and which ones I should drop.

Comment: “Translations”?  You’re using a bilingual dictionary? That won’t do at all.

Comment: Why is this separate from your last question? since both derive from the same source: "They reeled, whirled, swiveled, flounced, capered, gamboled, and spun. They leaped like deer on the moon." - Vonnegut, *Harrison Bergeron* . . . I'm flagging this.

Comment: @StoneyB - Why is this supposed to be put together with my last question? How does the fact that they are taken from the same source imply that I should be putting them all in the same question? Plus, to me it's quite obvious that "reel", "whirl", "swivel" and "spin" fall into one group, while "flounce","caper" and "gambol" fall into another group. Hence I have two separate questions for these two groups. What's so wrong about it? Man, you are flagging me just for this?!

Comment: @brilliant: The answer to your previous question pretty much answers this question as well. Since all these words are together in the same sentence, I think you probably should've asked it all in one question (and told more about where you got it to begin with). To me it's quite obvious that the author is using a rhetoric device to describe the dance of Harrison and the limber ballerina; the synonyms are not meant to be dissected and differentiated, but put together in a spontaneous, fluid dance of words. Why should you put them in the same question? Because they came from the same context.

Comment: @J.R. - Well, you are right about them all coming from the same context. But, if you read through my questions carefully, you'd see that I wasn't really asking about the context of the source, but rather about those words in a slightly different context - especially in the question on flounce, caper, and gambol - as my main interest was in how those words would be different in those new contexts - not in the context of the source, regarding which, by the way, I knew from the outset that the author was simply piling up similar words - a common technique in a fiction literature.

Comment: You should explain that when you ask; that way, people are far less likely to pounce, deride, inquire, scorn, and rebuke. Had you started with the Vonnegut quote, explained what you knew, added a few words from a dictionary, then asked your question by saying something like: "This quote has me wondering, are there any differences between these words? Are there times when I might use one over the other to describe a certain kind of dance?" I think there's a good chance you would've had less downvotes, and maybe even upvotes. [Observe the +10](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77988).

Comment: @J.R. (1) - "This quote has me wondering, are their any differences between these words? Are there times when I might use one over the other to describe a certain kind of dance?" - Well, thanks for telling me. However, before you told me this I really had no idea how to do that. I didn't even know how to phrase those questions that you told me here. All I thought was that not mentioning the source (since I wasn't at all asking about the source) was good enough/ I had no idea how well-known or poorly know the source was.

Comment: (2) Far less did I know that some people here like @StoneyB would start showing off their knowledge of the source and start rebuking or even deriding me. Here, again we are running into a long-term and a very painful problem: a non-native speaker simply doesn't know how to phrase his question properly, and a native speaker expects the non-native OP to phrase his question so well that in  fact if OP really could've done that, he would've had no need to ask a question.

Comment: You've asked a good number of questions here, and I assume you'll be asking more. Hopefully, this discussion will be beneficial, and some of your future questions will be improved thanks to this conversation. One pattern I've noticed on EL&U is that questions that ask "What's the meaning of…" or "What's the difference between…" with little or no context often get slammed with downvotes and comments like, "What did the dictionary say?" while questions that clearly include previous research are taken much more seriously. I'm not saying you should've known better, I'm merely trying to help.

Comment: brilliant, if I've done you an injustice I apologize. I did not go to the source until you posted your second question, and found that you were tampering with the evidence, whereupon I flagged it for moderator investigation. It had nothing to do with either the quality or the well-formedness of the question; rather, I've been on  forums/lists where the integrity of discussion was deliberately undermined by trolling (sometimes very subtle), and felt a question had to be raised.

Comment: @StoneyB - No problem StoneyB and no hard feelings. I think I also need to apologize to you for being too impulsive here.

Comment: I don't believe @StoneyB was showing off or deriding you, but your last comment brings up one other persistant problem: non-native speakers taking such rebukes as personal attacks when they are meant to be hints on how to ask better questions. When people ask, "What does the dictionary say?" we aren't demanding perfection in your attempt to form a question, we are simply saying, "First tell us what you've already figured out, and then we'll gladly help fill in the rest of the puzzle." Without context, though, it's hard to get even a toehold on a good answer – best to add as much as you can.

Comment: One last thing (now that all that is out of the way)... in answer to your question, I probably wouldn't use _flounce_, _caper_, or _gambol_ at all, not when describing kids in a playroom – they're simply not very common words. I might use _frolic_ instead. Maybe.

Comment: I, too, brilliant: I reacted too quickly. - This contretemps illustrates, by the way, why I have elected to encourage the proposed ELL site, so both questioners and answerers have a clearer notion of what's called for. It is chastening to realize that I have contributed to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the dictionary:

- *gambol*: To leap or spring, in dancing or sporting; now chiefly of animals or children.
- *caper*: intr. To dance or leap in a frolicsome manner, to skip for merriment; to prance as a horse. Also with about, away
- *flounce*: intr. To make abrupt and jerky movements with the limbs or body; to throw the body about; to plunge, flounder, struggle. Also with about, up. Usually said of bulls, horses, or aquatic animals. to flounce it, said of a woman dancing.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see how "to flounce" is different. However, I still don't quite see the difference between "to caper" and "to gambol". Is it like in "to caper" the element of happiness is kind of prevalent, while not in "to gambol"?

Comment: @brilliant - 'gambol' is almost always used of innocent play, while 'caper' *may* (but doesn't have to) suggest something awkward, grotesque, inappropriate. 'caper' still preserves, for many writers, its original association with the goat (caper is Latin for goat), which has in some contexts a sinister reputation.

Comment: @StoneyB - I see. "Caper" meaning "goat" in Latin is quite a precious insight here. Thank you.

Comment: @StoneyB I’m not sure that [cutting capers in the street](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69378/to-cut-capers-in-the-street) is particularly sinister, but something about this quote just might be: “He would cackle with laughter and caper, if any jest was made, or even if Frodo spoke kindly to him, and weep if Frodo rebuked him.”  The cackling doesn’t help. No, no points for guessing the ref. :)

Comment: @tchrist O, nice. . . Specifics I had in mind were *RIII* "He capers nimbly in a lady's chamber / To the lascivious pleasing of a lute", and *Huckleberry Finn*, where the King is described as capering in the pornographic version of the performance.